# Как получить связанные объекты при помощи EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Предположим у нас есть следующая структура классов:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие свойства    
    public int RoleId {get;set;}

    public Role Role {get;set;}
}
public class Role
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие свойства
    public ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions {get;set;}

    public Role()
    {
        Permissions = new List<Permission>()
    }
}
public class Permission
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие свойства    
    public ICollection<Role> Roles {get;set;}

    public Permission()
    {
        Roles = new List<Roles>();
    }
}
```

Как модифицировать указанные выше классы что бы можно было получить *связанные* сущности средствами *Entity Framework*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для того что бы получить *связанные объекты* средствами *Entity Framework* существует несколько способов:

1. **Eager loading** - *жадная* загрузка;
2. **Lazy loading** - *ленивая* загрузка;
3. **Explicitly lоading** - *явная* загрузка;

> *Жадная* загрузка - процесс при котором необходимо указать сущности которые необходимо загрузить сразу, это достигается путем указания необходимых сущностей при помощи метода `.Include()`

В этом случае для будет сформирован *один* запрос к бд который вернет *все* необходимые данные.

> *Ленивая* загрузка - процесс при котором связанные сущности подгружаются при первом обращении, необходимые свойства должны быть объявлены с указанием модификатора доступа `virtual`

В данном случае при обращение к навигационному свойству будет формироваться запрос к бд для получения необходимых данных

> *Явная* загрузка - процесс при котором связанные сущности подгружаются только если они явно подключены при помощи метода `.Load()`

в данном случае связанные сущности не будут подгружены до момента их *подключения* при помощи `.Load()`

Универсального решения о выборе между *ленивой/явной* и *жадной* загрузке - нет.

Загружать много редко используемой информации (особенно часто изменяемой)  - не эффективно, еще более не эффективно использовать *n+1 запросов* вместо одного, так как ленивая загрузка будет означать выполнение отдельного запроса для каждого объект. Если нужно, то можно использовать `.Load()` вместо `.Include()`

---

Например:

[*Жадная* загрузка](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

```
var user = context.Roles.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("Admin")).Include(x=>x.Permissions)
```

[*Ленивая* загрузка](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

Установим модификатор доступа `virtual` у свойства `Role` у класса `User`

```
public virtual Role Role {get;set;}
```

тогда получить роль пользователя можно будет получить так:

```
//получаем необходимого пользователя
var user = context.Users.Where(x=>x.Id==5)
//При обращении к свойству будет выполнен запрос к бд получающий связанную сущность.
var userRole = user.Role;
```

[*Явная* загрузка](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx):

может быть использована при отключенной *ленивой* загрузке(`context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`), либо при отсутствии модификатора доступа `virtual` у необходимого свойства

```
var role = context.Roles.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("Admin")).Single();
```

что бы получить связанные сущности в этом случае необходимо поступить так:

```
var usersRole = context.Entry(role).Collection(x => x.Users).Load();
```

Comment: @PavelMayorov хорошее замечание, может Вы бы оформили ответ по получению связанных объектов без *lazy loading*

Comment: оформлю, но позже

Comment: @PavelMayorov про тормоза я слышал, но в небольших продуктах можно наверно сильно не заморачиваться, а там где необходимо быстродействие *EF* вроде не используют. все Выше сказанное мое IMHO

Comment: Между хайлоадом и небольшими приложениями есть огромный пласт крупных, но слабонагруженных приложений. И там EF без ленивой загрузки еще как используют.

Comment: @PavelMayorov с нетерпением жду Вашего ответа :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34283/discussion-between-bald56rus-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 2):

Если используются сложные объекты, например вы хотите получить Users вместе в Roles, можно пользоваться

```
var a = context.Users.Include(w=>w.Roles);
```

Но я не до конца понял ваш вопрос

Comment: данный вопрос/ответ это следствие часто появляющихся вопросов по получению связанных объектов средствами *Entity Framework*. приведенный вами код насколько я знаю подразумевает загрузку связанный объектов сразу.

Comment: @Bald56rus: нет универсального решения о выборе между lazy loading и загрузке сразу. Если сразу загружать много редко испольуемой инфорации (особенно часто изменяемой), то это не эффективно. Еще более не эффективно использовать N+1 запросов вместо одного, так как lazy loading будет озночать выполнение **отдельной** подзагрузки на каждый объект. Если нужно, то можно использовать `.Load` вместо `.Include`. См примеры [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: @Oleg как я писал выше, вопрос/ответ скорее для того что бы другие подобные вопросы закрывать как дубликат, за время моего участия в данном сообществе подобных вопросов было чуть меньше 10, и ответ на каждый сводится к тому или иному способу. может Вы бы оформили ответом: возможные варианты с плюсами/минусами того или иного подхода. рейтингом Вас конечно не заманишь, но ведь здесь Мы и не из за него собрались

Comment: @Bald56rus: Если чесно говорить, то я вообще не любитель Entity Framework, потому что при этом легко написать два фрагмента, которые выглядят почти одинаково, но по скорости и по используемой памяти отлигаются в сотни раз. Я предпочитаю более понятный код в stored procedures. Код должен читаться без двусмысленностей и подводных камней, а Entity Framework, на мой взгляд, больше подкалкивает нас к другому стилю, где необходима постоянно контролировать SQL statements сгенерированные написанным кодом. Я предпочитаю писать SQL statements сам.

Comment: @Bald56rus: Напримр, сегодня я написал [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34764698/315935), из которого видно примерно, как я использую Entity Framework.

Comment: @Oleg я изменил свой первоначальный ответ, и воспользовался Вашим комментарием из данного ответа, надеюсь Вы не против

Comment: @Bald56rus: Конечно я не против! К тому же, я считаю правильным кратко изложить решение проблемы (или привести набор альтернати с их плюсами и минусами). В конце концов, основная цель stackoverflow - это делиться информацией с другими, а не просто разобраться самому.

Comment: @Bald56rus: Кстати, я забыл упомянуть дискуссию [здесь](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797) о реализации Lazy Loading в Entity Framework 7 в ASP.NET 5. Возможно, она будет интересна.