# Оптимизация запроса SelectMany Lazy Loading EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Имеется такая схема данных:

**Category**

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

**Product**

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...
    public int? StandartId { get; set; }
    public virtual Standart Standart { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

**Standart**

```
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

`Category` имеет древовидную структуру, `category` имеет дочерние элементы и родительский. `Category` имеет список `Products`. `Product` имеет один `Standart`. Один `Standart` может иметь несколько `Product`, находящихся в разных `Category`.

Мне необходимо при отображении категории, на той же странице, отображать список стандартов, находящихся в ней, при том, что стандарт не имеет прямой связи с категорией.

Я использую паттерн `Repository`. Код на выборку стандартов в категории такой:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Standart>> GetStandartsInCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            return await GetAllStandartsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var standarts =
            await categoryRepository.WhereAsync(c => c.ParentId == category.Id || c.Id == category.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return standarts.ToList().SelectMany(s => s.Products.Select(p => p.Standart)).Distinct();
    }
```

Всё бы вроде не плохо, но выполняется 33 запроса! 16 к Products, 17 к Standarts. Кол-во стандартов в БД = 17.

Как же быть с таким количеством запросов. Скорость отображения изменилась в 5 раза с применением данной выборки (было ~10ms, стало ~50ms, при втором+ запросе)

Comment: `standarts.ToList()` а если убрать этот `ToList`, как с запросами?

Comment: @Monk ничего не изменилось, ведь я в данном случае его использую для материализации после асинхроного запроса, и в памяти фильтрую (вообще это очень странно)

Comment: @АлександрСанков "ничего не изменилось", но могло, материализация обычно не захватывает ленивые коллекции. Тут надо думать над ситуацией, возможно стандартов в системе будет мало и их можно вытянуть все, а потом уже дофильтровать по вхождению в продукты.

Comment: @Bald, я добавил в свой Repository метод Include. Метод GetStandartsInCategory  я переписал так: categoryRepository.Include(c=>c.Products).Where(c => c.ParentId == category.Id || c.Id == category.Id).SelectMany(s => s.Products.Select(p => p.Standart)).Distinct(); Всё получилось, спасибо вам!!! Только вот в чем разница, и почему так, не смогли бы подсказать и оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы попробовал сделать например так:

```
using(var db = new DefaultContext())
{
    //вытягиваем на клиента вместе с категорией так же зависимые продукты
    var category = db.Categories
        .Include(x=>x.Products)
        .Where(x=>x.Id==categoryId)
        .Single();
}
```

---

Т.е. для тех категорий которые нам необходимы мы сразу вытягиваем из бд список зависимых данных, в вашем случае это `ICollection<Product> Products`.
либо можно было поступить следующим образом:

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(//).ToList();
db.Entry(categories).Colections(x=>x.Products).Load();
```

чуть более подробно можно посмотреть в другом моем ответе: [Как получить связанные объекты при помощи EF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482281/179270)