# Почему не сохраняется свойство?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Пишу авторизацию для чата с помощью Entity Framework. Все уже в общем то написано давно было, но когда стал пристально тестить обнаружил баг. Сущность пользователя выглядит так:

```
public class UserInfo
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  [Required, MinLength(4), MaxLength(32)]
  public string Username { get; set; }

  [Required, MinLength(4), MaxLength(32)]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  public long? RoleId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
  public RoleInfo Role { get; set; }

  public long? BanId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(BanId))]
  public BanInfo Ban { get; set; }
}
```

Так вот при регистрации создается UserInfo и RoleInfo, Role присваивается, сущность добавляется в список контекста и вызывается SaveChanges. Но авторизация потом работает только пока не остановишь сервер. При перезапуске сервера (и соответственно подгрузке БД) у сущности пропадает Role. Хотя там в отладчике видно что указан RoleId, но сама сущность Role остается в null. Почему так происходит? ForeignKey указан...

UPD. код контейнера:

```
public class DbContainer : DbContext
{
    public DbContainer() : base($"name={nameof(DbContainer)}") { }

    public virtual DbSet<UserInfo> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RoleInfo> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BanInfo> Bans { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Bald Т.е. как это дубликат это же ваш вопрос был. О_о

Comment: Дубликат в рамках данного ресурса а не от одного пользователя, в вашем случае ваш вопрос сводится к: *Как заполнить свойство значением из связанной таблицы.* на который есть ответ в моем вопросе/ответе

Comment: Получилось что ли у Вас *заполнить* свойство `Role`?

Comment: @Bald Да спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используются навигационные связи то тогда можно воспользоваться *ленивой* загрузкой, для этого необходимое свойство должно быть объявлено с использованием модификатора `virtual` тогда при первом обращении к свойству будет выполнен запрос к бд, который заполнит свойство `Role` иначе необходимо использовать *жадную*: `Include(x=>x.Role)` или *явную* `userInfo(x=>x.Role).Load()` загрузку

чуть более подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482281/179270)

P.S. решение 100% работает с подходом `code first`, для иных подходов может отличаться

Comment: Никак не могу понять что делает функция Include и куда ее вставлять. А вот это userInfo(x=>x.Role).Load() вообще выглядит очень странно. Как это вы ухитрились от переменной сделать вызов как от функции? Или что это? Да используется code first.

Comment: `Include()` подгружает значение `Role`, из *связанной* таблицы. подключать его надо приблизительно так: `context.UserInfo.Where(...).Include(x=>x.Role)`

Comment: Но ведь судя по тому что я прочитал по ссылке данной вами у меня используется ленивая загрузка и Include не нужен. Так почему же не работает?

Comment: @DarkByte `public RoleInfo Role { get; set; }` судя по этому у Вас не используется *ленивая* загрузка - отсутствует модификатор **virtual**, т.е. должно быть  **`public virtual RoleInfo Role { get; set; }`**

Comment: Ах вот оно что. Я думал в контейнере должно быть virtual, а оказывается еще и в сущностях. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @DarkByte вот как раз в контейнере `virtual` нафиг не нужен.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Я просто когда только начинал разбираться с этим EF начал с model first подхода. Создавал все в дизайнере, а когда переходил на code first делал по аналогии с кодом дизайнера. А там зачем то они помечаются автоматически как virtual.