# Как вывести в gridview данные связующей таблицы реляционной базы данных?

Tags: c#, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Есть простейшая база данных из 5 связных таблицы [image]
как вывести в gridview или какой-то другой контрол данные таблицы WorkOrded чтобы вместо айдишников полей связных таблиц

[image]

были интересующие меня поля, например, Operator.Fullname, Forester.FullName, Forest.ForestName и т.д.. Пробую разобраться с тем как это выполнить с помощью Entity Framework, но застряла и без вашей помощи не могу сдвинуться. SQL запросом я получаю искомые данные

```
SELECT        WorkOrder.Date, WorkOrder.CompleteStatus, Forester.FullName, Forest.TreeType, Forest.Square, Forest.ForestName
FROM            WorkOrder INNER JOIN
     Forester ON WorkOrder.idForester = Forester.id INNER JOIN
     Forest ON WorkOrder.idForest = Forest.id
```

но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. 
Спасибо большое за внимание, буду очень признательна за любую помощь.

Comment: Что за подход Вы используете: `CodeFirst`, `DatabaseFirst`, `ModelFirst`? если используется `CodeFirst` то обратите внимание на вот этот [вопрос/ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482282/179270)

Answer (score 2):

Вашу задачу можно решить несколькими способами:

Во-первых, как вы и делаете SQL-запросом, этот способ имеет тот недостаток, что он значительно запутывает ваш код и очень сильно затрудняет отладку и тестирование, кроме того он требует от вас хорошего знания языка SQL.

Во-вторых, вы можете перенести эти запросы на сторону базы данных, преобразовав их в процедуры или вью. Однако вычистив от этого кода свой проект, вы, вероятно, захламите саму базу данных и вам кроме того понадобятся дополнительные права в базе данных на создание и редактирование сущностей. Затруднения с отладкой, тестированием, а также требование к хорошему знанию SQL остаются.

И наконец, в-третьих -- родной способ для EF -- navigation properties. Существует два подхода к разработке в EF Database First и Code First.

**Database First:** этот подход сейчас "не моден" так как более трудоемок, требует хороших знаний SQL, доступа к серверу и определенных прав на нем. Однако так как существует много баз с ценными данными к которым обычно необходимо просто прикрутить интерфейс, он имеет право на жизнь, кроме того этот метод удобен для людей хорошо знающих SQL, либо когда в базе данных нужны какие то тонкие настройки. При этом подходе вы сначала создаете базу данных, а потом из нее генерите сущности. Навигационные свойства у вас будут созданы из вторичных ключей ваших таблиц.

**Code First:** Вы сначала описывает в своем коде необходимые вам сущности, а потом EF сгенерит по ним скрипт развертывания базы данных. Из вашей схемы мы возьмем две таблицы: WorkOrder и Operator и попробуем создать в коде навигационное свойство.

```
public partial class WorkOrder
{
    public int idWorkOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CompliteStatus { get; set; }

    //два свойства в этом классе
    public int idOperator { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}
public partial class Operator
{
    public Operator 
    {
         this.WorkOrders = new HashSet<WorkOrder>();
    }

    public int idOperator { get; set; } // Имена важны, привыкайте использовать
                                        // осмысленные имена, а не безликие I,
                                        // ID, Date, которые можно использовать
                                        // только с областью видимости private
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorState { get; set; }

    // Одно свойство в этом классе + не пропустите конструктор
    public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }
}
```

И наконец использования, я написал WPF вариант, приблизительно так как я делал бы сам:

```
using(MyDBContext context = new MuDBContext())
{
    var result = context.WorkOrder.Select(n => new { 
         ID = n.id
       , OperatorName = n.Operator.FullName
       , OperatorStatus = n.Operator.ServisorStatus
       //остальные необходимые поля 
       });

    GridViewViewer.DataContext = result;
}
```

Более подробно о Navigation properties можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) или [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: <Зануда>1. Публичные свойства/методы в [tag:c#] принято именовать в Pascal Case, т.е. `IdWorkOrder`; 2. В [tag:entity-framework] есть [рекомендации](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) по поводу именования ключевых полей: либо просто `Id` или же `WorkOrderId`(Primary key/Foreign key conventions)</Зануда>

Comment: @Bald -<Зануда> я старался сделать имена как в вопросе. Что человек не потерялся, читая ответ. За исключение совсем уж безликих ІD -- их я просто не люблю</Зануда>