# При создании списка элементов из БД Entity Framework "подтягиваются" не все данные

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть такой код:

```
 public static List<Model.Stores> SelectStoresForTable(string reg="", string rtl="", string reprInitials="")
{
    IQueryable<Model.Stores> query = db.stores;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reg))
       query = query.Where(s => s.region.Name == reg);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtl))
       query = query.Where(s => s.rtl.Name == rtl);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reprInitials))
       query = query.Where(s => s.repr.initials == rtl);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Этот код, если есть какие-то параметры не по умолчанию, отсеивает по ним данные; если нет, то возвращает список всех магазинов. В каждом магазине есть отношения с другими объектами (регион, человек и т. д.).
**И в итоговый список выгружаются только "простые переменные"(string и id), а все зависимости равны null (человек, регион и т. д.).**
Никак не могу понять, в чём проблема. В базе данных эти зависимости есть.
Похоже на какую-то ошибку в самой Entity Framework.
У меня CodeFirst база данных.

Если я включаю программу с заполненной БД, то ошибка есть. Если я дропаю таблицы из запущенной программы и загружаю в них информацию заново, то всё работает как часы. Может, кто-то сталкивался?

Заранее очень признателен.
**Update:
Ответ на вопрос получил благодаря @Bald
Еще очень важный момент, у меня не был подключен:**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

**Поэтому я не мог вводить в .Include() анонимные функции.**

Comment: советую обратить внимание вот на этот [вопрос/ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482281/179270). по умолчанию EF не загружает *связанные* данные Вы должны ему сказать об этом, при помощи `Include(x=>x.Навигационное свойство) / Load()` или же воспользоваться *ленивой* загрузкой. более подробно в приведенной ссылке

Comment: Привет, Bald. Спасибо тебе огромное. Я примерно понял в чем проблема. Просто система не грузит все, что может быть "лишним". А покажи пожалуйста пример, где мне нужно загрузить при помощи "жадной загрузки" reg, rtl, repr(см. мой код)

Comment: если в двух словах то да. если данные нужны то лучше воспользоваться *жадной* `Include()` загрузкой

Comment: А покажи пожалуйста пример, где мне нужно загрузить при помощи "жадной загрузки" reg, rtl, repr(см. мой код). То есть у меня три "сложных" параметра. Спасибо! И мне нужен весь список db.stores

Comment: я бы наверно сделал так: `query.Include(x=>x.region).Include(x=>x.rtl)` где `region`, `rtl` имя навигационных свойств, лучше всего загрузку связанных сущностей сделать до *материализации* что бы был один запрос к бд.

Comment: http://SSMaker.ru/5e303a69/   почему-то в моем случае Include запрашивает строку и не дает вызвать параметры x.---

Comment: необходимо подключить `using System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Вооо! Сработало! Ты - лучший, @Bald . Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @VladimirBorisenko кстати, на свежевбитых данных все работает скорее всего потому, что вы используете один долгоживущий контекст. Это может быть плохим решением - особенно если в вашей программе много данных, и если она работает с базой не одна. Создавайте новый экземпляр контекста на каждую выборку, с оборачиванием его в using.

Comment: Перенесите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы из вопроса в ответ и поставьте у ответа галочку, что вопрос решен.

Comment: @PashaPash да, так и есть. У меня статический класс для работы с БД. Услышал замечание, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Andrew B с телефона не понял как сделать, сегодня займусь. Спасибо огромное ребят!

Comment: @Bald запостите свой ответ как ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос получил благодаря @Bald :

> советую обратить внимание вот на этот [вопрос/ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/482281/179270). по умолчанию EF не
>   загружает связанные данные Вы должны ему сказать об этом, при помощи
>   Include(x=>x.Навигационное свойство) / Load() или же воспользоваться
>   ленивой загрузкой. более подробно в приведенной ссылке

Еще очень важный момент, у меня не был подключен:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Поэтому я не мог вводить в .Include() анонимные функции.
Так же @PashaPash помог мне разобраться почему срабатывали свежезагруженные данные:

> @VladimirBorisenko кстати, на свежевбитых данных все работает скорее
>   всего потому, что вы используете один долгоживущий контекст. Это может
>   быть плохим решением - особенно если в вашей программе много данных, и
>   если она работает с базой не одна. Создавайте новый экземпляр
>   контекста на каждую выборку, с оборачиванием его в using

Спасибо всем огромное, ребят!:-)