# LINQ пропускает строки если в ячейке NULL

Tags: c#, linq

Есть таблица в которой могут быть ячейки в строке пустые. Их тоже надо вывести. LINQ пропускает эти строки и не отображает их.

```
IEnumerable<AllOrderView> select =
    (from order in db.RetailOrders
     join status in db.RetailStatus on order.StatusId equals status.Id
     join customer in db.RetailCustomers on order.RetailCustomerId equals customer.Id
     orderby order.Id descending
     select new AllOrderView
     {
         Id = order.Id,
         FirstName = customer.FirstName,
         LastName = customer.LastName,
         Phone = customer.Phone,
         StatusName = status.StatusName,
         Sum = (int)order.Sum,
         DateTimes = order.Data,
         Comment = order.Comment
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: так у Вас же `join` а вам надо `left join`

Comment: @Bald, благодарю. Помогло

Comment: @Bald: Ну так оформите ответом?

Comment: @VladD попытался опубликовать ответ, критика приветствуется

Comment: @Bald: Ничего не могу сказать против. </критика>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Вас реализовано *внутреннее* соединение, тогда как Вам необходимо *левое* соединение.

---

исправьте `linq` запрос следующим образом:

```
join status in db.RetailStatus on order.StatusId equals status.Id into rs
from status in rs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join customer in db.RetailCustomers on order.RetailCustomerId equals customer.Id into rc
from customer in rc.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

`Select` в данном случае будет тот же самый, за исключением того что надо обработать ситуацию `null` в *левой* таблице, я бы это сделал например так:

```
  Status = rs?.Status ?? string.Empty
```

В данном примере я воспользовался нововведениями 6 версии языка [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
 `?.` - так называемый [*элвис*](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.26.php) оператор

[Виды соединений в SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512206/179270)

---

Так же для получения *связанных* сущностей можно воспользоваться *навигационными* свойствами, 
тогда запрос примет следующий вид:

```
from o in Orders
select new
{
    Status = o.Status?.Name ?? string.Empty
}
```

Способ создания навигационного свойства зависит от используемого linq-провайдера. Например, при использовании EF подхода *code first* объявление навигационных свойств выглядит так:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OrderStatusId {get;set;}

    //Навигационное свойство
    public virtual OrderStatus Status {get;set;}
}
public class OrderStatus
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

[более подробно про получение связанных сущностей при использовании EF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482282/179270)

Comment: Стоило бы упомянуть про навигационные свойства, которые также решают эту проблему.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за подсказку, что то я даже не подумал об этом. чуть позже дополню ответ

Comment: @PavelMayorov дополнил способом получения при помощи *навигационных* свойств

Comment: теперь есть другая проблема - вы неявно предполагаете использование EF Code First. А может использоваться тот же linq2sql.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я правильно понимаю что при подходе `linq2sql` заполнение навигационного свойства происходит в ручную в `linq` запросе?

Comment: Нет конечно же. Запросы для всех трех провайдеров (EF Code First, EF Model First, Linq2Sql) выглядят одинаковыми, по запросу нельзя определить что он использует. А вот определение навигационного свойства делается по-разному.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52715/discussion-between-bald-and-pavel-mayorov).