# Передача модели во view

Tags: c#, mvc

Есть 2 модели, программы и пользователи:

```
public class Prog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int? ProgId { get; set; }
    public virtual Prog Prog { get; set; }
}
```

Сделал view на основе модели Prog. И хочу туда передать коллекцию моделей программы, что бы передать во view все программы что есть, а во view пробежаться по всем пользователям всех программ и вывести этих самых пользователей в таблицу.

Но выходит ошибка, вот код контроллера и view:

```
Context db = new Context();
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        IEnumerable<Prog> progs = db.Progs;

        return View(progs);
    }
```

Представление:

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Prog

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер строки</th>
            <th>Название программы</th>
            <th>Фамилия пользователя</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                <td>@item.Prog.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Surname</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Я только начал изучать mvc. Можно ли так реализовать то что я хочу, или для этого нужно использовать например ViewBag? Неужели способ с переданием модельки только на 1 экземпляр? Не может же быть такого.

Comment: Стёр уже две версии ответа. Давайте определимся: вы хотите выбрать из базы все программы и к каждой подписать список пользователей? Или вы хотите выбрать список всех пользователей и каждому приписать программы (если они есть)? У вас разные куски кода противоречат друг другу.

Comment: @AK В таблицу я хочу вывести список всех пользователей и у каждого программу если она есть, но делаю я это вот так как я привёл в коде. Я беру модель программ и передаю её во view А там уже у программ смотрю всех пользователей. Возможно как то замудрено, просто нашёл такой вот вариант. Если я сделаю вью на основе модели User в таком случая я не знаюкак пробежаться по всем пользователям, поэтому и выбрал такой вот вариант как у меня в коде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action:

```
public ActionResult User()
{
    IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users.Include(x => x.Prog).ToArray();
    var model = users; // Не люблю передавать через ViewBag
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.User>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>UserSurName</th>
            <th>Название программы</th>
            <th>Фамилия пользователя</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@user.Id</th>
                <th scope="row">@user.Surname</th>
                @if(user.Prog != null)
                {
                    <td>@user.Prog.Name</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>–</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Этот вариант минимально рабочий, начните с него.

Давайте попробуем понять, что у вас представление будет на основе IEnumerable - вы сами сказали " хочу вывести список всех пользователей и у каждого...", поэтому мы в действии пишем:

```
    IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;
    return View(users);
```

И в представлении пишем:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.User>

@foreach (var user in Model) {}
```

Пока понятно?

Но если мы сделаем так, то мы не сможем обратиться к user.Prog - потому что они не подтянуты из базы (ну точнее, если lazy loading выключен, но это [отдельный момент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482282/213987), вы его никак не затрагивали в вопросе).

Поэтому нужно подтянуть в запросе через `.Include(x => x.Prog)` ещё и программы - ну и не забывать проверять на NULL.

Про то, что не стоит передавать через ViewBag - а стоит делать полноценные модели - это дело вкусовщины, но я тоже не люблю передавать через ViewBag. Более подробно это раскрыто в ответе Дмитрия.

Comment: Извините, привёл пример не того контроллера, сейчас поменял код.

Comment: @Андрей Это совершенно неважно, что у вас был за контроллер, вы уже достаточно пояснили, что вы хотите что там должно быть.

Comment: AK пробую ваш вариант `IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users.Include(x => x.Prog).ToArray();` в лямбда выражении ошибка `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

Comment: @Андрей Подключите `using System.Data.Entity;` в начале файла. (А вот если бы у вас стоял решарпер - он бы вам сам предложил бы такой using)

Comment: Большое спасибо, вариант с `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.User>` помог. Примерно это я и хотел найти, не знал что так можно. Спасибо ещё раз, буду дальше изучать mvc.

Comment: 15 версия студии умеет тоже предлагать `using` если вызвать контекстное меню на ошибке `Ctrl+.`

Comment: @AK а скажите пожалуйста, как включить lazy loading? Просто без инклюда у меня не подтаскиваются программы.

Comment: @Андрей Лучше и не включайте никогда. Я всегда держу в коде this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false и всегда явно управляю тем, что загружать и когда загружать. Если хочется включить - то путь на тёмную сторону начинается [где-то здесь](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php). Не говорите только потом, что вас не предупреждали ;)

Answer (score 3):

Для передачи данных во `View` есть два способа.

**1. Через модель.**

В случае, если это более сложная модель чем у вас уже есть необходимо создать специальный класс для этого случая, в `MVC` такие классы называются `ViewModel` классы. То есть классы данных для `View`.

```
public class OnePlusTwoViewModel 
{
   public User User { get;set; }
   public IEnumerable Programs { get; set; }
}
```

Его инициализировать в действии контроллера и передать во `View`.

`View` инициализируется моделью этого класса

```
@model OnePlusTwoViewModel
```

**2. Использовать `ViewBag`**.

```
ViewBag.user = user;
ViewBag.programs = programs;
```

**3. Совмещённый способ.**

Так же есть возможность объединения этих подходов, то есть часть данных передать через модель, а часть через `ViewBag`.

В обычных ситуациях такой способ передачи стоит избегать.

**В случае вашего вопроса** если вы хотите во `View` вывести только пользователей, то список пользователей вам надо сформировать в действии и во `View` передать этот список.

Основной принцип работы MVC это то что во `View` передаются уже подготовленные данные.

```
public ActionResult Progs()
{
    var progs = db.Progs.Include(x => x.Users).ToList();
    var users = new List<User>();
    foreach(var prog in progs) {
       users.AddRange(prog.Users);
    }
    return View(users);
}

@model IEnumerable<User>
...
```

В вашем случае код можно оптимизировать.

```
public ActionResult Progs()
{
    var users = db.Users.Include(x => x.Prog).Where(x=>x.ProgId != null).ToList();
    return View(users);
}
```

Незабываем подключить `using System.Data.Entity;` для работы `Include`.

Comment: Извините, привёл пример не того контроллера, вот сейчас поменял код.

Comment: Попробовал сделать через лист вот так вот: `List<Prog> progs = db.Progs.ToList(); return View(progs);`
В итоге ошибка `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List 1[WebApplication3.Models.Prog], but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication3.Models.Prog'.`

Comment: @Андрей обновил код

Comment: Дмитрий, ошибка на инклюде, такая же как и в варианте у AK. В чём дело не могу понять.

Comment: @Андрей там нужно неймспейс заюзать, сейчас скажу какую. Пока можете попробовать Include("Progs")

Comment: Кстати, вы зря указываете строкой инклуд: лучше пишите x => x.Progs - так вы получаете автокомплит, проверку на опечатки при компиляции (а не вылет в рантайме) и лёгкость рефакторинга (решарпер внутрь строк не полезет, а лямбду поймёт.

Comment: @AK согласен... Я обычно так и делаю, но в ответах иногда проскакивает...

Comment: @AK: Или `nameof`?

Comment: @VladD Тоже должно сработать.